# the generation of parse tree of StanfordCoreNLP is stuck

Tags: scala, stanford-nlp, parse-tree

When I use the StanfordCoreNLP to generate the parse using bigdata on Spark, one of the tasks had stuck for a long time. I looked for the error, it showed as follows:

```
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel.(CoreLabel.java:68)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel$CoreLabelFactory.newLabel(CoreLabel.java:248)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.LabeledScoredTreeFactory.newLeaf(LabeledScoredTreeFactory.java:51)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Debinarizer.transformTreeHelper(Debinarizer.java:27)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Debinarizer.transformTreeHelper(Debinarizer.java:34)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Debinarizer.transformTreeHelper(Debinarizer.java:34)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Debinarizer.transformTreeHelper(Debinarizer.java:34)
      at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Debinarizer.transformTreeHelper(Debinarizer.java:34)
```

the relevant codes I think are as follows:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
import java.util.Properties
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object CoreNLP {
    def transform(Content: String): String = {
        val v = new CoreNLP
        v.runEnglishAnnotators(Content);
        v.runChineseAnnotators(Content)
    }
}

class CoreNLP {
    def runEnglishAnnotators(inputContent: String): String = {
        var document = new Annotation(inputContent)
        val props = new Properties
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse")
        val coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
        coreNLP.annotate(document)
        parserOutput(document)
    }

    def runChineseAnnotators(inputContent: String): String = {
        var document = new Annotation(inputContent)
        val props = new Properties
        val corenlp = new StanfordCoreNLP("StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties")
        corenlp.annotate(document)
        parserOutput(document)
    }

    def parserOutput(document: Annotation): String = { 
        val sentences = document.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
        var result = ""
        for (sentence: CoreMap <- sentences) { 
        val tree = sentence.get(classOf[TreeAnnotation])
        //output the  tree to file
        result = result + "\n" + tree.toString
    }
    result
    }
}
```

My classmate said the data used to test is recurse and thus the NLP is endlessly run. I don't know whether it's true.

Comment: How long is the sentence that is causing the problem?

Comment: Around 300KB's data. And I found another question recently. When I run the program(runChineseAnnotators() ) mentioned above, and the test text is a very long String. It throws an exception: NumberFormatException: multiple points

Comment: NumberFormatException: multiple points
at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.ChineseQuantifiableEntityNormalizer.normalizedNumberString

Comment: How many tokens are in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");` to your code that will set the parser to not parse sentences longer than 100 tokens.  That can help prevent crash issues.  You should experiment with the best max sentence length for your application.

Comment: Well, I didn't describle the question thoroughly. I use the NLP to process Chinese and I don't know how to set the 'props' of Chinese. The only operation I know is:

         StanfordCoreNLP corenlp = new StanfordCoreNLP("StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");

Could you tell me how to set the props? Thanks for answer me question.

Comment: In Scala I think you want to load the Chinese properties from the file: prop.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file")) and then set this extra property.

Comment: Well, the 'parse.maxlen' is hard to set because my data is larger than 40G and I use spark to process it in parallel with RDD. I don't know how large the data in every RDD is.
But I find another way to handle it. That is to edit the property file called 'StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties'. My purpose of using StanfordNLP is to get the parse tree. I delete several parameters and only 'tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse' remain. I don't know whether it's reasonable and could you please give me some advice?